# Add button on top of frame layout

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, android-framelayout

I have a `FrameLayout` with the background set to a UI I created in photoshop. I want to know how to add buttons in xml on top of the buttons I created in photoshop. How do I get the locations ?

Please attachment for UI [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yddd.jpg) and link of github for source code of project. Please feel free to clone and check out
https://github.com/ksasso1028/Sassoshots

Answer (score 0):

> How do i get the locations ?

Short answer: you don't.

Your best bet is to determine the dimensions and position in the original file taking into account its resolution and then try to place the buttons in your layout with that in mind.